# How to understand recursive generic type constraint in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

While I understand generic types `<T>` and `where` clause for constraint, I was confused about the following code from Unity Tower Defense Template:

```
public abstract class Singleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : Singleton<T>
```

What's the purpose of restricting the type to be itself?

Comment: Do you have a link to where we can see that in-context?

Answer (score 0):

It prevents you from doing this:

```
public class A
{
}

public class B : Singleton<A>
{
}
```

You will get a compile error.  Due to the type constraint, you must write:

```
public class A : Singleton<A>
{
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking why would you _want_ that compiler error? i.e. _what's so wrong_ with `class B : Singleton<A>`? It doesn't stop `B` from being a singleton, and `A` can also still be a singleton - it depends entirely on other details not included in the OP's question.

Comment: Also note that if you have `public class A : Singleton<A>` then you can also have `public class B : Singleton<A>`

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, one possible benefit of this is allowing methods to return the specific type. This is done by *fluent style* methods. Another example, obviously not applicable to the example you posted, is a *Copy()* method that returns a copy of the object as the derived type rather than as its base type. The method signatures of the Singleton< T> class you posted likely show where it uses the T parameter and likely hint at the reason why it uses this pattern.